# Doesn't show all remote branchs with git branch -r

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, remote-branch

when I execute the command:

git branch -r, it's show just:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/development-elton
  origin/master
```

And when execute the command:

git remote show origin, it's show:

```
 remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:r2a_/grconsig.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:r2a_/grconsig.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    caio-dev                   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    controle-usuario           new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    development-elton tracked
    master                     tracked
    rails-admin                new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    **refinancy            new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)**
```

How make for pull the branch refinancy for my local?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on [mipadi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35734061/1677912):

To see all remote branches (with a single remote):

```
git fetch
git branch -r
```

To see all remote branches (with multiple remotes):

```
git remote -v //shows names and URLs of remotes
git fetch --all
git branch -r
```

Answer (score 15):

If the existing answers are not sufficient, you can check your `.git/config` file. In my case, I had the following section:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/John/project1
        fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I've edited the file to:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/John/project1
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And then, I was able to fetch all branches with `git fetch`.

This happens sometimes, if you change the remote repository with:

```
git remote set-url origin  https://github.com/John/project1
```

Comment: after adding `[remote "origin"]` I was able to `git fetch --all` my branches from Gitlab. Some explanations can be found here: https://gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-remote-section-git-config/

Comment: Thank you! This work, but how can I set this to default. It's create on every clone the wrong config!

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `git fetch` to get the latest branches.